# Names from localstorage into array to random name picker

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to make a random name picker from an array of names taken from localstorage which seems that the error isn't popping up when i inspect it with google chrome.

Here's my code:

```
function getUserData() {
    var Detail = localStorage.getItem("Detail");

    if (Detail == null) {
        Detail = []; // on new computer, create the local storage item } else { 
        Detail = JSON.parse(Detail); // convert from string to array
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < Detail.length; i++) { // loop through the array
        var row = document.getElementById("Detail").insertRow(-1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
        cell1.innerHTML = Detail[i].name;
        cell2.innerHTML = Detail[i].admin;
        cell3.innerHTML = Detail[i].email;
        cell4.innerHTML = Detail[i].contact;
        cell5.innerHTML = Detail[i].country;
    }
}

function NamePicker() {
    var Detail = localStorage.getItem("Detail");

    if (Detail == null) {
        Detail = []; // on new computer, create the local storage item
    } else {
        Detail = JSON.parse(Detail); // convert from string to array
    }

    // copy names
    var nameArray = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < Detail.length; i++) { // loop through the array
        nameArray[i] = Detail[i].name;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < Detail.length; i++) { // loop through the array
        // get a number from random num generator %numArray.length
        name = nameArray[num];

        while (nameArray.length < 11) {
            var randomnumber = Math.max(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 11))
            var found = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++) {
                if (name[i] == randomnumber) {
                    found = true;
                    break
                }
            }
            if (!found) name[nameArray.length] = randomnumber;
        }

        // Display using modal
        alert(name);

        // remove using splice(num, 1);
        name.splice(num, 1);
        document.getElementById("Detail").innerHTML = name;
    }
}
```

the problem is that it seems that `num` isn't removing the name from the list and alert function isn't popping up...
i really appreciate the help thanks in advance...

Comment: The `} else {` in the comment in the first function is a typo in the question only? `Detail = []; // ... } else {`

Comment: since you are looping through the name array in the second for loop, I would use nameArray.length instead of Detail.length

Comment: where did num come from exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I found a couple of problems in you second function; you are using the local variable i in three for loops, and I think in one of them you meant to use num. Also, I changed Detail.length to nameArray.length in the second for loop since you are going through the nameArray. I also change the third for loop to use z instead of i.

```
function NamePicker() {
var Detail = localStorage.getItem("Detail");

if (Detail == null) {
    Detail = []; // on new computer, create the local storage item
} else {
    Detail = JSON.parse(Detail); // convert from string to array
}

// copy names
var nameArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < Detail.length; i++) { // loop through the array
    nameArray[i] = Detail[i].name;
}

for (var num = 0; num < nameArray.length; num++) { // loop through the array
    // get a number from random num generator %numArray.length
    name = nameArray[num];

    while (nameArray.length < 11) {
        var randomnumber = Math.max(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 11))
        var found = false;
        for (var z = 0; z < nameArray.length; z++) {
            if (name[z] == randomnumber) {
                found = true;
                break
            }
        }
        if (!found) name[nameArray.length] = randomnumber;
    }

    // Display using modal
    alert(name);

    // remove using splice(num, 1);
    name.splice(num, 1);
    document.getElementById("Detail").innerHTML = name;
}
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I've tried the code you've given me.
It works, there was no error when i inspect element on google chrome.
But my webpage went unresponsive when i used the function...

Comment: I think there might be a problem with the while loop also. make sure the condition you give it happens, otherwise it is an infinite loop. now you are checking the nameArray.length < 11, but i don't see you adding anything to it, so I doubt  this condition in being met. Or may be what you meant was name.length < 11

Comment: The nameArray.length has the value from Detail value
I'm definitely not using name.length because that will also make it an infinite loop

Comment: The thing is in the while loop you are not increasing the size of nameArray, so if its size was less than 11 it will always be less than 11.

Comment: I followed your advice and did the following.
name = (nameArray[num] =+ 1);
 .but it went infinite loop again...

Comment: This does not increase the size of nameArray, it just adds 1  to the element at index num in the nameArray. If you want to add something to an array you can look into the JavaScript push() method on array objects

Comment: ' var random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4) for (var num = random; num < nameArray.length; num++) { 
  %numArray.length
  name = nameArray[num];
  var randomnumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4)

  while (nameArray[num].length < 4) {
   var found = false;
   for (var z = randomnumber; z < nameArray[num].length; z++) {
    if (name[z] == randomnumber) {
     found = true;
     break;
    }
   }
   if (!found) name[nameArray[num].length] = randomnumber;
  } ' . This is the code i've tried... I'm sorry but i just started java this year and i'm not very knowledgeable in this section.